# Как прописать if в dart в 1 строку

Tags: dart

Смотрите в питоне можно создавать переменные так: txt = 5 if n % 2 == 0 else 10
А как в dart прописать такое же
И
В питоне можно писать if вот так: print(511) if 4 % 2 == 0 else print(12412)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В dart есть [условный оператор](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#conditional-expressions) `?:`

```dart
var txt = n % 2 == 0 ? 5 : 10;
```